# Selecting only integer data within a column with characters

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to write a query that will select items with only integer data such as: 019280498 as opposed to 0129830INK.  These are sku's in a product database and my current solution is something to this effect:

Column name is **SKU**

```
SELECT *
FROM mydb
WHERE SKU not like '%a%' or SKU not like '%b%' or SKU not like '%c%' ..... or SKU not like '%z%'
```

This would only return values with no characters in them.  However it does not like what I have written and i'm sure there is a more elegant way to execute this.

Comment: Does your version of SQL support `regular expressions`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using your original method with `like`, you can do:

```
SELECT *
FROM mydb
WHERE SKU not like '%[^0-9]%';
```

This has the advantage that expressions like `'3e9'` are not accepted as a numeric value.

Or, if is specifically alphabetic characters that you want to keep out:

```
SELECT *
FROM mydb
WHERE SKU not like '%[a-z]%';  -- or for case sensitive collations '%[a-zA-Z]%'
```

Comment: +1. This takes into account the fact that `ISNUMERIC` allows more than just digits

Answer (score 3):

There's an IsNumeric() function that could be used.

```
Select *
from mydb
Where IsNumeric(sku) = 0x1
```

Comment: Yes and I made a mistake, it is Server 2008 not 2012.  Updated the title.

Comment: @ZachM. You should know that `ISNUMERIC` will return true for some chars as `.` or `E`. Test `SELECT ISNUMERIC('01234.6E10')` for instance

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Pincode 
FROM ps_all_india_pin_code 
WHERE Pincode between '100000' and '999999'
```

Comment: Could you please format your code by highlighting it and hitting Ctrl+K